# ASP.NET Core 3.1. *.cshtml location not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a shared project which I'm using to keep common tools. The structure is as follows

```
shared.csproj 
     +
     +---Hangfire/
            +
            +---Authentication/
                     +
                     +---Controllers/
                     +      +
                     +      +---Login.cs
                     +
                     +---Views/
                            +
                            +---Login/
                                  +
                                  +---Index.cshtml
```

In this project I have a CommonStartup class in which I'm configuring part of my Services and in ConfigureServices method I've specified where my Views are along wiht other service configuration unrelated to my issue.

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        configuration.ViewLocationFormats.Add("Hangfire/Authentication/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    });

   ...
}
```

In the Configure method of the CommonStartup, I'm configuring part of my pipeline

```
publi void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    .....

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());


    app.UseSession();
    app.UseHangfireDashboard(...);
}
```

shared.csproj is referenced in service1.csproj , service2.csproj ,....

In service1 Startup.cs file

```
public class Startup : CommonStartup 
{
    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         base.ConfigureServices(services);
 
         ... service1 services
    }
}
```

Now when starting service1 and asking for {service1}:{port}/login, I'm being redirect to login action found found in shared.csproj /Hangfire/Authentication/Controllers/Login/{Index}

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
```

but it fails to serve the view.

And this is the exception

> The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were
> searched:\r\nHangfire/Authentication/Views/Login/Index.cshtml\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1
> originalLocations)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ViewResult result)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, IActionResult result)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n

I have a git link to test locally and repreduce, required tools .NET Core 3.1 sdk https://github.com/remus-corneliu/test

I think that the issue is that the files are not present in the entry assembly -> Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), in this case servcie1. The search pattersn are

Views/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}.cshtml

Hangfure/Authentication/Views/Login

and I believe are applied to the EntryAssembly, so when calling service1:{port}/login, the assembly from which the request originates is the servie1 which does not contain the .cshtml files nor the structure, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: In configrure service, add mvc

Comment: Try using `Add("/Hangfire/...")` or `Add("~/Hangfire/...")` instead of `Add("Hangfire/...")` . It sometimes works.